# Pager not displaying correct navigation in View panel for categorized view in IBM notes 9

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have created single category back end view. I mapped back end view to view panel control in xpages in notes 9 and set the following property to open xpage view in collapse mode.

expandLevel is "1" in All Properties of xpage view panel.

Initially view panel is displaying in collapsed mode. when i expand any category, its expand the category and show the list of document(Default 30 entries will display). I like to navigate to next page to see  rest of document and categories. But when i expand the category, **pager page count** is not changed. its not calculating the pages. I unable to find link enable to navigate in pager.

Its work for me in notes 853 and notes 852.

any one else facing issue? To reproduce issue just create single category backend view(make sure have more document to display in more pages) and map to xpage view control and disable expand level property

Its not work for me in both web browser and xpinc.

is problem with notes 9?  or something else? Do i need to enable any other setting in notes 9 to make work?

Comment: There's 2 fixes for IBM Notes 9, have you installed them and see if it solves the problem? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21636023#Notes and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21640580 . Both seems to have fixes on pager although I'm not sure if it applies to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Using categories in views is not a recommended UI pattern for web applications, so you might actually consider [using an alternative](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-7UDMQS).